# Finding an ID on different models

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to find an ID from different models.

My original table has a listing of the Tasks. However, task details are different so once added, it will be added to different Models/Tables.

Code below will try to find a task_id from different models. As I need to view the details for that Task.
But was hoping for something cleaner. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Here's my code

```
public function Task(Tasks $id) {

$Model1 = Model1::where('tasks_id, $id)->pluck('id')->first();
$Model2 = Model2::where('tasks_id, $id)->pluck('id')->first();

if ($Model1 != null) {
  $this->Data = Model1:find($Model1)->get();
 }

else if ($Model2 != null) {
 $this->Data = Model2:find($Model2)->get();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function Task(Tasks $id) {

    $models = ["Model1","Model2"];
    foreach ($models as $model){
        if($modelID = $model::where('tasks_id', $id)->pluck('id')->first()){
            $this->Data = $model::find($modelID)->get();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above may have an unnecessary query and could be simplified further:

```
public function Task(Tasks $id) {

    $models = ["Model1","Model2"];
    foreach ($models as $model){
        $this->Data = $model::where('tasks_id', $id)->get();
        if ($this->Data != null){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

One further optimization:

```
public function Task(Tasks $id) {

    $models = ["Model1","Model2"];
    foreach ($models as $model){
        if (null != $this->Data = $model::where('tasks_id', $id)->get()){
           break;
        }
    }
}
```